# Варианты тестирования приложения при переносе БД в Android и iOs

Tags: android, ios, testng

Добрый день!

Следующая ситуация :

1. У нас есть старенькая версия мобильного приложения, которая сейчас выложена в AppStore и Google Play.
2. В разработке находится новая версия приложения, разрабатывалась с нуля на основе функционала старого приложения. В нем изменился дизайн и добавили новый функционал.
3. База в приложении храниться локально, нет

Главная задача, при обновление приложения через AppStore / Google Play со старой версии на новую вся информация должна остаться и перейти в новое приложение.

iOs ранее core data  , а станет realm. 
Android ранее sqlite, сейчас sqlite .

После того как мы закончим разработку,мы должны передать заказчику конечную версию, которую он будет выкладывать в сторы.

Необходимо протестировать и быть на 100% уверенными что при обновление приложения старая база не затрется. Если на Android это сделать не сложно - выложить старую версию, а затем выложить новую и протестировать, то по iOs есть большие опасения что этого не получиться сделать. 
Может кто подсказать варианты для проверки и тестирования на iOs?

Answer (score 0):

Для этого есть TestFlight
https://developer.apple.com/testflight/

Выкладывайте обе версии в TestFlight и устанавливайте, обновляйте, удаляйте как угодно и в любом порядке.

Comment: Спасибо! 
А разве при установке через testflight старая информация полностью не удаляется из приложения?

Comment: Нет, насколько я знаю. TestFlight пишет Update на кнопке, так что это должен быть нормальный апдейт.

Comment: Спасибо, попробуем!